# Transverse displacement profile of the string using Fourier series

Tags: waves, fourier-transform, string

A string of length $L$ fixed at $x=0$ and $x=L$ and released at time time $t=0$, the transverse displacement at a position $x$ along the string is given by: $y(x,0)=Ax(L-x)$

Assuming that the string is released from rest, write down
an expression for $y(x, t)$, the transverse displacement profile of the string at an
arbitrary later time.

My solution:

The initial displacement $y(x, 0)$ is can be represented as a sum of harmonic $y(x,0)=∑_{(n=1)}^∞a_n y_n (x) $   where $y_n(x)=\sin⁡(nπx/L)$    and  $a_n=\frac{4AL^2 (1-(-1)^n )}{(π^3 n^3 )}$.

This is the part i am struggling with:

$y(x,t)=∑_{(n=1)}^∞(\frac{4AL^2 (1-(-1)^n )}{(π^3 n^3 )})(\sin⁡(nπx/L)) \cos(πvnt/L)$

Comment: What exactly are you struggling with? You have a term for the solution, do you believe it to be incorrect? Why don't you plot it for $t=0$ and compare it with $x(L-x)$?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the problem is, exactly, so let me know if I've got it wrong. I have below a plot for the case $L=1$.

1. The blue line represents the function $y(x) = x(1-x)$,
2. The orange line represents the function $$y_1(x) = 4 \left(\frac{1- (-1)^1}{\pi^3 1^3}\right) \sin{(\pi x)},$$
3. The green line represent the function $$y_3(x) = \sum_{n=1}^3 4 \left(\frac{1- (-1)^n}{\pi^3 n^3}\right) \sin{(n \pi x)}$$

(I've leave it to you to figure out why I didn't plot $y_2(x)$.)

If you can't see the difference between the green and blue lines, it's because this Fourier Series converges extremely fast to give a very good approximation of the function!

However, if you are looking for a *closed form* solution to the series, I'm afraid you're going to be disappointed. *Mathematica* tells me there is one using special functions, but it's too horrid to write down here, and frankly doesn't give you much more information than this series does.

[image]